# Ubuntu 18.04 javafx.utils not there

Tags: java, linux, javafx, sdn

I am trying to 'build' Floodlight. I've stumbled upon compilation issue that is fairly self-explanatory, i.e:

```
> compile:
>     [javac] Compiling 593 source files to /mnt/sda1/floodlight/floodlight/target/bin
>     [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
>     [javac] /mnt/sda1/floodlight/floodlight/src/main/java/net/floodlightcontroller/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.java:57:
> error: package javafx.util does not exist
>     [javac] import javafx.util.Pair;
>     [javac]                   ^
>     [javac] /mnt/sda1/floodlight/floodlight/src/main/java/net/floodlightcontroller/statistics/IStatisticsService.java:10:
> error: package javafx.util does not exist
>     [javac] import javafx.util.Pair;
>     [javac]                   ^
>     [javac] /mnt/sda1/floodlight/floodlight/src/main/java/net/floodlightcontroller/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.java:138:
> error: cannot find symbol
>     [javac]     protected HashMap<Pair<Match,DatapathId>,String> flowToVipId;
>     [javac]                       ^
>     [javac]   symbol:   class Pair
>     [javac]   location: class LoadBalancer
>     [javac] /mnt/sda1/floodlight/floodlight/src/main/java/net/floodlightcontroller/statistics/IStatisticsService.java:25:
> error: cannot find symbol
```

[and so on]

I've of course tried adding javafx via apt like this:

```
root@hp-linux: apt install openjfx

root@hp-linux:/mnt/sda1/floodlight/floodlight# dpkg-query -L openjfx
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/openjfx
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/TODO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/copyright
/usr/share/openjfx
/usr/share/openjfx/lib
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.properties
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.base.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.controls.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.fxml.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.graphics.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.media.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.swing.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.web.jar
```

It seems like indeed, javafx.utils is not there. How do I fix that ? I've tried pretty much everything I've been able to find in the Internet, but to no avail.

Comment: The version of Ubuntu is not germane, but the JDK version is.  They've removed JavaFX from the JDK as of version 11.  It's still there for JDK 10 and earlier.  Which one do you have?  This means that you'll have to add JavaFX as an external dependency in your Maven pom.xml.

Comment: I've got OpenJDK 11. Could you please tell me how do I add external dependency ? The project is built with ant (never heard of maven).

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx/11

Comment: Hmm I've added the external dep to pom.xml (after <dependencies>), but the error persists.

Comment: Pair is in JavaFX base.  The [source is here](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/javafx/util/Pair.java).  If you don't need or want a dependency on the entire JavaFX system, you could just copy the source of javafx/util/Pair.java to your project source tree.  If you do that you will also need the dependent [javafx.beans.NamedArg](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/javafx/beans/NamedArg.java) class.

Comment: `javafx.util` is part of the `javafx.base` module (see https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/module-summary.html). Since `javafx.base.jar` is listed, I don't think this is an issue of the data not being on your device. It's more likely to be an classpath/module issue...

Comment: Never heard of Maven?  Time to learn. Maven is a dependency and lifecycle manager.

Comment: Did you set `PATH_TO_FX` to be `/usr/share/openjfx/lib`?

Comment: Setting a path on your local machine won't help if you deploy somewhere else.  How do you package and deploy this app?  JAR, WAR, something else?  Add the necessary JARs to your CLASSPATH in the package and you won't have a problem.  It won't do to add them to your Linux system.  You need to make the Java FX JARs available to your app.  The best way to do that is CLASSPATH.

Comment: @duffymo using the module path as outlined in [openjfx.io doc Modular Images | Modular with Maven](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular) and [`jlink`](https://www.baeldung.com/jlink) for distribution is a valid alternative to using the class path.

Comment: I use Spring Boot and use Maven to generate an executable JAR for me with all the dependencies packaged inside.  I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @RomeoNinov : Yes, I have. Does not work.

Comment: @duffymo: I'm following this how-to: https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/floodlightcontroller/pages/1343544/Installation+Guide#InstallationGuide-FloodlightMasterandAbove

Comment: Good luck. Class path is fundamental to Java. You need to make this work.

Comment: Neither following the 'Getting Started with JavaFX' nor setting CLASSPATH helps in any way.

Comment: I have even downloaded java from oracle, but it still does not work :-(

Answer (score 2):

As openjfx is no longer supported upstream, Ubuntu 18.04 decided not to support openjfx 8 anymore and replaced it with openjfx 11. If you are an SDN-man you should know that Floodlight supports Java 8 and so the problem will be found here.
I shared a post right now that I wish could help you. 
[How to install Floodlight controller on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside with Openjfx](https://medium.com/@s.hesam.ghasemi/how-to-install-floodlight-controller-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-alongside-with-openjfx-2b617c8b0d66?sk=3f57851b6a52622e60406f1e9f4503e5)

Comment: Link only answers are generally [not advised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).